# White screen when generating Electron.js executable with Nuxt 3

Tags: typescript, vue.js, electron-builder

I am following the Nuxt 3 modules documentation to create a desktop executable file for a website with Electron.js. Although I can run the `npm run dev` command and view an Electron.js window, when running the "npx electron-builder --win" command, the generated executable displays a blank screen and I can't view anything in DevTools. I tried changing the Vue Router setting to hashMode, but that didn't solve the problem. Additionally, when trying to run using Electron Forge, the screen also goes blank, and I can't identify the cause of this behavior.
Regarding DevTools, I also didn't find a solution
Other libraries like Tauri.js also return this same problem
nuxt.config.ts

```
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  ssr: false,
  router: {
    options: {
      hashMode: true
    }
  },
  modules: ['nuxt-electron'],
  electron: {
    build: [
      {
        // Main-Process entry file of the Electron App.
        entry: 'electron/main.ts',
      },
      
    ],
  },
})
```

electron > main.ts

```
import { app, BrowserWindow } from 'electron'

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  new BrowserWindow().loadURL(process.env.VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL).someBrowserWindow.webContents.openDevTools()someBrowserWindow.setMenu(someMenu)

})
```

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "nuxt-app",
  "private": true,

  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My Electron App Description",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "dist-electron/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "nuxt": "^3.10.3",
    "vue": "^3.4.19",
    "vue-router": "^4.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^28.2.4",
    "electron-builder": "^24.12.0",
    "nuxt-electron": "^0.7.0",
    "vite-plugin-electron": "^0.28.2",
    "vite-plugin-electron-renderer": "^0.14.5"
  },
  "build": {
    "win": {
      "extraResources": [
        {
          "from": "path/to/d3dcompiler_47.dll",
          "to": "."
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Tentei criar um executavel de um site para software mas nao deu certo pois abriu em branco o arquivo